# 'very_good' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: flutter

I tried to activate `very_good_cli` in flutter with this command:

```
dart pub global activate very_good_cli
```

and result was this:

```
...
...
...
Building package executables...
Built very_good_cli:very_good.
Installed executable very_good.
Warning: Pub installs executables into ~\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated very_good_cli 0.7.2.
```

I also added `~\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` to system Path, but this warning still persists and the error I get is:

```
'very_good' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after running `dart pub global activate very_good_cli` and adding path to `...\Pub\Cache\bin` to the Path in system environment variables, **restarting** the windows solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to quickly put this together to make it obvious.

After running the command...`dart pub global activate very_good_cli`
the bat file `very_good.bat` will be automatically added to your `~\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` directory. So, you need your command-line shell to pick up on this change.

As mentioned above, if you run `dart pub global activate very_good_cli` a second time it will give you some good info in the form of a warning

```
Warning: Pub installs executables into `~\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin`, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated very_good_cli 0.7.2.
```

So, if the warning states the `~\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` is not in your path, you need to add it there. [Something like this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). This essentially allows your command-shell to recognize 'very_good' as a command.

[Link to video showing the process of adding to path](https://youtu.be/66jocFjOeu4?t=152)

Once you are done with that, you need your command-line shell(s) to pick up the change. Easiest way to do that is to close them completely and reopen them. A tricky situation you might run into is if you are using a shell inside of another process. I use powershell terminal in vscode. So, I had to close vscode to actually refresh the terminal.

Restarting your computer is the nuclear button that should get the issue resolved if your Environment Variables are setup correctly or if there isn't some other wonky issue with the shell you are using. Using the built in windows cmd is a good test to see if it is just a problem with your preferred shell.

Comment: To be clear, don't add '/very_good' to '~\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin'. I was confused about this.